# Convergence of intervals in the sense of Hausdorff distance

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, metric-spaces

For the definition of Hausdorff distance, please see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance)

Suppose I have a sequence of interval $I_n=[a_n,b_n]\subset [0,1]$, then I read in a paper it says that, up to a subsequence, $I_n\to I$ in the sense of Hausdorff distance, where $I=[a,b]$ and $a=\lim_n a_n$ and $b=\lim_n b_n$. (up to a subsequence, by compactness of real numbers, we have $(a_n)$ has a subsequence convergence to $a$, same hold for $(b_n)$)

The paper does not prove it nor provide a reference. Maybe it is a very simple fact but I can't find it anywhere in my topology book. Is there any know a good reference for this fact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this would be stated as a theorem or lemma anywhere; the statement follows directly from the fact that 
$$d_H([a,b],[c,d]) = \max(|a-c|,|b-d|)\tag{1}$$

Indeed, the $\delta$-neighborhood of $[a,b]$ is $[a-\delta,b+\delta]$. This contains $[c,d]$ if and only if
$$\delta\ge \max(a-c, d-b)$$
Similarly, the $\delta$-neighborhood of $[c,d]$ contains $[a,b]$ 
if and only if
$$\delta\ge \max(c-a, b-d)$$
Combine these to get $(1)$.